# How to control copy/paste output on PDF (from specification)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Wondering how to control copy/paste output on a PDF like in this [LaTeX example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422424/control-the-copy-paste-output-of-latex-text). Essentially, you could just have this in the PDF:

```
a : x → y
```

And have it output in copy/paste to:

```
a : x -> y
```

More generally, I could have some text in the PDF like this:

```
foo bar
```

And it would copy/paste like this:

```
Hello world!
```

Wondering if there is anywhere in the [PDF spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) that describes how to do this. A search for copy/paste in the spec doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: *"A search for copy/paste in the spec doesn't reveal anything."* -  for a simple reason, pdf is a file format, not a GUI. What you are looking for, most likely you'll find searching for "Extraction of Text Content".

Comment: The PDF standard allows for an entry in a Font called ToUnicode which is CMap from which you create any unicode mapping you want. So in your example you could map "f" to "He" for example. Any conforming PDF reader is supposed to use this ToUnicode map when doing copy/paste. This affects any other text extraction, not just copy/paste. E.g. searching for "He" would highlight the "f" glyphs.